# Load 1D array from xml with linq

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, linq

I,ve searched a bit, but didn't find anythings that I think is right for an answer, I'm using a XDocument to load my xml, but I'm having some trouble to transform it into an array

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
  <sNone>
    <October>3.21</October>
    <November>-5.41</November>
    <December>-15.81</December>
    <January>-21.69</January>
    <February>-21.70</February>
    <March>-12.60</March>
    <April>-6.41</April>
    <May>-0.06</May>
    <June>5.42</June>
    <July>13.32</July>
    <August>14.12</August>
    <September>7.55</September>
  </sNone>

  <sLichen>
    <October>1.99</October>
    ...
</sLichen>
</document>
```

I'm loading my XML like so

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse();
```

but I'm confused on how to return a 1D array because I have multiple descendant.

EDIT

What I'm aiming to get is an array like this

{3.21, -5.41, -15.81, -21.69, -21.70, -12.60, -6.41, -0.06, 5.42, 13.32, 14.12, 7.55}

Comment: well, yeah.  If you really need to flatten this into a 1D array or List then it's pretty much up to you what that looks like.  It would be easier to deserialize it into an custom object though

Comment: A 1D array of what? The elements in `sNone` doesn't have the same name, should it map to a class?. What to do with `sLichen`? You need to give more information for us to help you out.

Comment: But I only need to load one descendant at a time, that's why I,m consufed

Comment: @SimonBelanger I don't understand what you are asking, I have a xml file filled with descendant of different name so I guess I could do something `doc.Root.Elements("sNone").Select(...)` but I don't know what to select...

Comment: You can probably achieve this using .Elements() or .Descendants() on "sNone" node, and then apply .Select() to map it on array ?

Comment: that's what I don't know how, to use or apply the select correctly

Comment: Ok. I've answered with a bit of code, see me reply under.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick :

```
var doc = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?....";
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(doc);
var items = xdoc.Root.Elements("sNone").Descendants().Select(d => d.Value).ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(items);
```

Or if you want decimals :

```
var items2 = xdoc.Root.Elements("sNone").Descendants().Select(d => decimal.Parse(d.Value)).ToArray();
```

Hope this helps.